# How to execute an event in a loop until the event is true

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, dom-events

I'm stuck in Javascript at looping a piece of code when an event listener is being
placed.

For example, let's say I have a div:

```
<div id="option">
</div>
```

and I added a Javascript `mouseenter` event listener:

```
const divItem = document.getElementById("option")
divItem.addEventListner("mouseenter", () => {
    console.log("Mouse is entered")
})
```

Now the console log happens once and after I hover the mouse, but I want it to happen every after 4 seconds
and log the same message in the console until the mouse is moving out of the div.

I tried using `setTimeout`:

```
divItem.addEventListner("mouseenter", () => {
    const timeoutEvent = () => {
         console.log("Mouse is entered")
         setTimeout( () => { timeoutEvent() }, 4000 )
    }
    timeoutEvent()
})
```

but it is logging even after the mouse left the div,
so how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. If you want every four seconds, you want to:

- Use `setInterval` (or set a new `setTimeout` every time), and
- Cancel it when you see `mouseleave`

```js
const divItem = document.getElementById("option")
// The timer handle so we can cancel it
let timer = 0; // A real timer handle is never 0, so we can use it as a flag
divItem.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    console.log("Mouse is entered");
    timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (timer) {
            console.log("Mouse is still here");
        }
    }, 1000);
})
divItem.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    console.log("Mouse left");
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = 0;
});
```

```html
<div id="option">
this is the div
</div>
```

*(I've used one second in that example instead of four so it's easier to see it working.)*

Or using `setTimeout` rescheduling itself instead:

```js
const divItem = document.getElementById("option")
// The timer handle so we can cancel it
let timer = 0; // A real timer handle is never 0, so we can use it as a flag
const timerInterval = 1000;
function tick() {
    if (timer) {
        console.log("Mouse is still here");
        timer = setTimeout(tick, timerInterval);
    }
}
divItem.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    console.log("Mouse is entered");
    timer = setTimeout(tick, timerInterval);
})
divItem.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    console.log("Mouse left");
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = 0;
});
```

```html
<div id="option">
this is the div
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

You can define your 'interval'  function and the interval in global scope and then use them to set and start the interval execution and  clearInterval ( stop de execution )  on mouseenter/mouseleave events.

```js
const divItem = document.getElementById("option")
let myInterval;
const timeoutEvent = () => {
  console.log("Mouse is entered")
}
divItem.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  myInterval = setInterval(timeoutEvent, 1000);
})
divItem.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => clearInterval(myInterval))
```

```html
<div id="option">
  My Option
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
divItem.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    console.log("Mouse is entered");
    timer = setInterval(() => {
            console.log("Mouse is still here");
        }
    }, 4000);
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.